# Get UserName in Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.net app which is being hosted on a server. I want to get the Clients username from the system and use that name as a title for an XML file im saving on the server. 
I have tried various different mathods such as:
Environment.UserName();
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

However all that keeps returning is the NetworkService account  name on the server.

Can anyone assist with this.

thank you

Comment: The methods you used gives you the user that is running the thread handling the user`s request. That is by default the user that is configured to run the application pool that the app in running in. What you need is sonthing else, that the guys here pointed out how to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web application is running (by default) under the NetworkService account. If you want to know the username of the user's NT account you should check out *impersonation*. With that the application will be running with the credentials of the user.

For public websites this is not possible or shouldn't be done. But internal company applications could do so.

Answer (score 7):

Given that your application has [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) set up (either Forms or Windows Authentication), you can get the current user's name via:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Tried this but it still returns the NetwrokService account

Answer (score 1):

If your users are [authenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) you can use [User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

This will only work if a user is authenticated by either Forms/Membership authentication or Windows, you can check beforehand:

```
string userName = "Anonymous";
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

you want the user name of the web client and WindowsIdentity or Env.UserName return you the server side user name, which might be the same as the web client user name only if you have enabled authentication.

I think to solve your issue you should look in the Request headers, in one of those headers there should be a username or useragent string telling you what you need.