# How can I get the current user's computer name, if my web app is on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have tried using UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName but that crashes my app. But on local it gets the logged in username.

Comment: That didn't work for me, I want to name of the logged in user

Comment: I picked that dupe based on your title, but I see now you want the user's name, not the computer name. Unless the users is authenticated in your web app, that is not something that's really supported. You can look at these two questions for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220292/get-username-in-web-app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232208/get-windows-user-name-using-javascript